# Submit second form after submiting first form

Tags: jquery, html, submit

i have a problem, i have two different forms, first one will submit something and after the first one is submit i wanna automatically submit second one.

So here's code:

```
<form action="" method="post" name="form1" id="form1">
<input type="submit" value="Send" id="SubmitForm1">
</form>

<form action="/somelink.html" method="post" name="form2" id="form2">
<input type="submit" value="Send" id="SubmitForm2">
</form>
```

and jquery

```
$('#form1').submit(function(){    
    $('#SubmitForm1').submit(); 
    $('#SubmitForm2').submit();  
});
```

So i'm a little stuck here

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: After first form is posted, i wanna post second one.
Second one need to be posted after first one, so two forms with one submit.

Comment: You want it so whenever the first form has been submitted it'll automatically show the next form for the user to fill in?

Comment: why do you have 2 forms in the first place...?

Comment: I'm posting first form and filling value from the first one to second one. It need to be like this.

So when i'm posting first form, i wann automatically post second form.

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to solve a problem that should never need to be solved. You are going about this the wrong way. Tell us exactly what you are trying to achieve and we can suggest a better way

Comment: With first form i'm posting values in second form. That's all. 
When the first form is submited i wanna submit another form. That need to be like this.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to submit 2 forms at the same time. One method I've used is creating a hidden form in addition to your 2 forms, and putting your two forms' values in that form and submitting it.

It might be a good idea to look into `.serialize()` from the jQuery API Documentation [here](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/).

Answer (score 0):

So this is what i needed all time, it's so simple.

```
<script> document.form2.submit(); </script>
```